# mysql multiple joins returns nothing

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 tables:
divisions (ID, Division)
teams (ID, Team)
scores(ID, RelationID, Score)
relatives (ID, RelationID, FieldID, ValID)

The relatives table is to 'link' divisions and teams by RelationID
The FieldID defines the table (1=divisions; 2=teams)
The ValID = the ID of the given table.
So, my fk is a combination of FieldID & ValID

The output should look something like this:

```
  Southwest Division | Tomcats  | 17
  Southwest Division | Bears    | 12
  Northeast Division | Tomcats  | 20
  Northeast Division | Lions    | 8
  Northeast Division | Cheetahs | 13
  Southeast Division | Cheetahs | 19
  Southeast Division | Lions    | 12
  Southeast Division | Zebras   | 6
```

Any given team can be in any division.

My Sql is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT divisions.Division, teams.Team, AVG(scores.Score) AS Score FROM 
(answers INNER JOIN 
  ((relatives
    INNER JOIN divisions ON relatives.FieldID = 1 AND relatives.ValID = divisions.ID)
    INNER JOIN teams ON relatives.FieldID = 2 AND relatives.ValID = teams.ID)
        ON answers.RelationID = relatives.RelationID)
  GROUP BY Division, Team
  ORDER BY Division, Team
```

This sql returns no records. Even if I remove the answers, GROUP and ORDER BY I get no records.

How can I make the tables return what I need?
I'd redesign the whole thing if needed.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Access? The parentheses around your join make this look like Access to me. Also, there is no need for `DISTINCT` here when you are grouping by division anyways. I don't think it's your problem, but worth noting I suppose.

Comment: Another question, why are you selecting from `answers`? You never mention that table anywhere in your question. Could that be part of your problem?

Comment: I wondered when I'd get busted on the 'answers' table:) The scores are answers. The table I'm using for testing is scores and that's just a mistake in my post here.
I neglected to point out that more than 1 division and/or more than 1 team can be affiliated with 1 score. Also, a given team can be affiliated with multiple divisions and visa versa.

Comment: Oh, no I'm using MySql. I guess the parens are a convention from old programming days in Access & Sql Server.

Comment: Here is a dump of the tables so you can recreate them easily in MySql.:
http://aecperformance.com/JoinsTest.txt

Comment: Business Logic:
The teams table amounts to a table of values. The divisions table amounts to a table of values. 
There is no implicit connection between teams and divisions.
A person enters the score and attributes the score to a combination of divisions and/or teams.

Multiple divisions may be 'attributed to' a given score. Multiple teams may also be 'attributed to' a given score.
So a given score could be 'attributed to' 2 divisions and 3 teams (ie a 'relationship').
Further, more than 1 score may be attributed to the same 2 divisions and 3 teams (ie the same relationship).

Comment: I need to be able to produce reports that show for each division, for each team what the average score was.
I need to be able to show it as teams per division OR divisions per team.